# How to destroy Wordpress User session from outside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have wordpress site which manages users in a custom php way , i have problem while i try to logout social signup users from custom php users , it doesn't logout wp-admin , how can i achieve this , please help ,

```
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

I tried this session destroy method , but it doesn't destroy wp-admin users.

Comment: Need more information, what is your custom php users? Are you just wanting to end the session, are cookies used? Are both the wordpress users, and your custom php users (file?) in the same directory?

Comment: Yes i just want to end session , No Cookies are used , Custom php users file i place it in root of wordpress folder. And Social signup users are stored in wp-users table and also in my custom table for php . Once i click logout i need to destroy wp-admin users